# Why can't I use the update function to update a flow in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

I hope to use Code A to update a flow, but I find the Flow `soundDensityState` isn't updated.

But Code B workes, what's problem with Code A ?

**Code A**

```
private val _soundDensityState = MutableStateFlow(MSoundDensity() )
val soundDensityState = _soundDensityState.asStateFlow()

fun beginSoundDensity(filename: String){       
    myJob = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        aSoundMeter.getMSoundDensity().cancellable().collect {
            _soundDensityState.update { it }
        }
    }
}
```

**Code B**

```
private val _soundDensityState = MutableStateFlow(MSoundDensity() )
val soundDensityState = _soundDensityState.asStateFlow()

fun beginSoundDensity(filename: String){
    myJob = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        aSoundMeter.getMSoundDensity().cancellable().collect {
            _soundDensityState.value =it 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StateFlow` is not updating because of the name shadowing, as parameters of `update` and `collect` lambdas have the same name `it`.

It can be resolved by giving either of the `lambda` a different name. Change the name of `collect` lambda to `soundDensity` and use that in `update`.

```
private val _soundDensityState = MutableStateFlow(MSoundDensity() )
val soundDensityState = _soundDensityState.asStateFlow()

fun beginSoundDensity(filename: String){
    myJob = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        aSoundMeter.getMSoundDensity().cancellable().collect { soundDesity ->
            _soundDensityState.update { soundDesity }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`it` in that lambda is a parameter of `update` holding the current value of the StateFlow. It is shadowing the `it` of the `collect` lambda.

Comment: Thanks! Does it mean that I can't use Code A to update a flow?

Comment: You can if you name your lambda parameter in one of the two lambdas. However, the point of using `update` is to compute the next value using the previous value and to do it atomically (the flow will be locked from the value being updated from elsewhere while the update lambda is running). Very narrow use case. In your case, Code B is preferable because it isn’t atomic. `update` should only be used if you need it because it will perform worse.